# jQuery: Offset and position return same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to detect an element inside a table. However, jquery return the same value for both offset and position. What I want is the position of the element relative to the table column.

Why is my jQuery offset and position both return the same value? The value that is returned is actually the offset value. How can I get the position value?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test offset & position</title>
</head>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
table.table tbody tr td{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Rendering engine</th>
     <th>Browser</th>
     <th>Platform(s)</th>
     <th>Engine version</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><select name="select" class="detect">
     <option>100</option>
     <option>20</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
   </select>
   <div class="cover"></div></td>
   <td><p>Internet
    Explorer 4.0</p>
    <p>dsfds</p>
    <p>df</p></td>
    <td><textarea class="detect">4444  444

     dsfdsfdsf ds fds f

     dsf
     ds
     fsd
     fs</textarea></td>
     <td><div><textarea class="detect">4</textarea></div></td>
   </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $(".detect").focus(function(e) {
    console.log("height:"+$(this).height()+" width:"+$(this).width()+" position top:"+$(this).position().top+" position left:"+$(this).position().left +" offset top:"+$(this).offset().top+" offset left:"+$(this).offset().left);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and jQuery code.

Comment: I have already edit the post with my code.

Comment: `offset()` and `position()` are returning different values for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/s9ucs/

Comment: That's funny. I tried with firefox, chrome, IE again and again. It returns the same value.

Comment: Using Chrome 30, I get: `height:18 width:46 position top:108 position left:8 offset top:110 offset left:10` in the console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

position returns the position relative to the offset parent, and offset does the same relative to the document. Obviously, if the document is the offset parent, which is often the case, these will be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add position:relative; to parent element